# rewrite link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following link

```
www.site.com/4/5
```

what should look like

```
www.site.com/1/2/3/4/5
```

Can I make a rule with htacces to override the wrong link?

Comment: Are `/1/2/3` always the same thing?

Comment: This is very unclear. What is the link the user will visit, and what do you want it rewritten in?

Comment: And should the user's browser be redirected to /1/2/3/4/5, or should the correct page just be served down without redirecting?

Comment: actually not but I could manage like static link

Comment: actually the user is browsing a wrong link www.site.com/4/5 and thats why should be rewritten to www.site.com/1/2/3/4/5.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of site.com.

If you use Rule1, comment out rule 2 and vice versa.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#1 to just rewrite server side use this rule
RewriteRule ^4/5$ /1/2/3/4/5 [L]


#2 to change the URL to 1/2/3/4/5 in the users browser, use this rule
RewriteRule ^4/5$ /1/2/3/4/5 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks I've been trying but without any results. The problem seems to be more complex. I'm using joomla with joomsef set it up. For the content the basic joomla sef is used and for zoo component an implemented seo plug-in under joomsef.From here one I'm getting all the troubles. This plugin doesn't want to add the 2nd and 3th menu levels titles to the link.